# BackboneJS: Load more items into a collection

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mongodb, backbone.js

In Backbone JS when I fetch a collection should I be fetching the entire collection or a small portion of it?

For example I have news feed collection in mongoDB that could have potentially 1000s of items. When the user hits the page I only want to show them the latest 10 items with the option to 'Load More'. But if they visit a specific item via URL `http://site.com/#/feed/:itemID` I want to be able to pull up that item's record.

**1. How many document should I be fetching initially?**

**2. How would I got about fetching any item by id?**

Answer (score 13):

I ended up using the `{add: true}` statement when calling fetch on my collection. This prevents the collection from being replaced by the result of the fetch and but instead appends the result to the collection. I then also passed the 'skip' amount using the `{data: {skip: amountOfItemsInCollectionAlready }`, this is used on the server-side to get the correct batch of items from the database.

**My final fetch method looks like this:**

```
    loadMore: function(e){

        this.collection.fetch({
            add: true,// this adds to collection instead of replacing
            data:{// this is optional params to be sent with request
                skip: this.collection.length// skip the number of items already in the collection
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I was wondering if this was the preferred way of doing it! The other options seemed like more work than needed.

Comment: Just a note for Backbone 0.9.10 users: fetch() no longer accepts the `add: true` option. You can achieve the same thing however with `{update: true, remove: false}`

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't want to just use `Collection.fetch()`, because you won't get the benefit of client-side caching - it'll drop the items you've already loaded from the server and reset the collection. You will probably need to extend `Backbone.Collection` with a custom function to retrieve more items. I used the following code in a recent project:

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // fetch list without overwriting existing objects (copied from fetch())
    fetchNew: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        var collection = this,
            success = options.success;
        options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
            _(collection.parse(resp, xhr)).each(function(item) {
                if (!collection.get(item.id)) {
                    collection.add(item, {silent:true});
                }
            });
            if (!options.silent) collection.trigger('reset', collection, options);
            if (success) success(collection, resp);
        };
        return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
    }

});
```

This is mostly copied from the default `fetch()` code, but instead of dropping existing items it will add new ones. You'd probably want to implement something server-side, using the `options` object as `Julien` suggests to pass in the parameters of what items you want to load, probably either a page number (if you want to control page size on the server) or a start-stop pair (if you want to control it on the client).

Answer (score 3):

1 - You should be fetching 10

Add a page argument to your collection and have the backend code return the page matching (10/page). /my_objects?page=2 to get records 10-20 etc.

You do this like this (untested):

```
collection.fetch({data: {page:2}})
```

Or you alter the URL directly

2 - To fetch an item by ID you create the model

```
object = new Model({id: 1})
```

and fetch it

```
object.fetch()
```

Comment: **1.** Ok right so it is only necessary to have the data that is currently on the page in your backbone collections? 


**2.** To fetch a model from the backend I have to first create it using the relevant ID and then call fetch. Will this trigger an "add" event on that collection? Or as far as Backbone is concerned that Model is in no collection?

Comment: Also what is the "page argument" you speak of? Is this the function that constructed the 'url' attribute? eg. `url: function(){ return x + "/" + y + "/" + z;`

Comment: 1. Right. 2. No you will have to add it to the relevant collection. 3. You can use the url attributes, but I think in the most recent versions of backbone you can send options to the ajax call with fetch, refresh etc. fetch({data: "your query here"})

Comment: I am trying to create a news feed similar to Facebook. Users new to be able to add items to the feed and load in older items. This involves new items being prepended to the feed and sent to the server to be saved and older items being appended to the feed in chunks of ten. Still a little consfused hwo this would work.